# Deleting Exchange server .log files with Powershell script

Tags: powershell

```
$time = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
$path = "C:\Source_Folder"
Get-ChildItem -path = $path -include E00000*.log -Recurse -Force | `
Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $time } | `
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

---

This is my current code for deleting old log files (Older than 7 days.) 
Files are called `E00000****.log` 
There are files in the folder that is not supposed to be deleted that are .log 
files that are older than But I don't seem to get it to work.

If anyone would be so kind to take the time to explain how I would go ahead and do it, I would be very grateful. I got som programming knowledge but trying to learn powershell. Thank you.

Comment: This is flag is something I found in a code for deleting .temp files that where older than 30 days. 
It might be wrong though. I'll try without the flag. Is there a diffrent flag that would be more appropriate?

Comment: Sorry, brain hasn't kicked in yet.  Give me a minute and if no one smarter has come by, I'll respond.

Comment: I will take any input possible. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, so you want to delete any file called "E00000*.log" within "$path" and include subdirectories, right?  As long as it's more than 7 days old?

Comment: *But I don't seem to get it to work* can you please explain how it does not do what you expect?

Comment: It ran before... But it didn't do anything. As far as I can see.
And I think I just figured out why. My test files where .txt not .log... *Facepalm*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking you want:

```
$time = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
$path = "C:\Source_Folder"
Get-ChildItem "$path\E00000*.log" -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $time } | Remove-Item -Force
```

Again, I apologize as I'm running slow this morning.

Comment: That worked as far as I can see! thank you. I'll do a proper test tomorrow on one of the Exchangeservers we have here.

Comment: I wasn't sure if that code up there was your original code since someone edited it (assuming to add `code` tags) but you had some extraneous stuff in your code, so I eliminated it and changed your `Get-ChildItem` request to exactly for what you were searching.  Good luck!